# How to remove specific value from div section using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a div where it contain dynamic labels. I am trying to remove specific value from div section using jquery.I have declared variable which conatin the string if the string matches in the div section string it should get removed from div. Is there any way to to do that?

```
      <div class="VS" id="MM" style="border:1px solid gray; width:150px;">
      <label class="custom_label_div2" id="lbl1"> XYZ </label>
      <label class="custom_label_div2" id="lbl2"> XYZC </label>
      <label class="custom_label_div2" id="lbl3"> QWER </label>
      <div>
```

I was trying to do something like this

```
    var str = XYZ; --- this is my varibale which will contain any label deriving from somewhere else it can contain any one of the value i.e. XYZ or XYZC or QWER
    $('#MM').each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       if ($this.text() === str) {
           $this.remove();
       }
    });
```

Comment: What is `this`? None of the labels have `btn` in their ID and do would not match the pattern to replace. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Twisty i have made the changes , if XYZ is in div then i want to remove that label

Comment: Again, you have a jQuery selector `$('#9MMM')` but there is no element with an `id` of "9MMM" … you have your `<div … id="MM" …>` so you would want `$('MM').each(…)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this.text() === str) {
           $this.remove();
       }
```

- this is removing the element itself, if you need to empty it use :

```
if ($this.text() === str) {
           $this.text("");
       }
```

or

```
if ($this.text() === str) {
           $this.html(""); // if there are other elements inside
       }
```

or just

```
if ($this.text() === str) {
           $this.empty();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Your JQuery string finds only the div with id "MM", but You want the child elements so try this:

```
var str = XYZ;
$('#9MMM > label').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() === str) {
        $this.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have made the changes in my queation

Comment: the above answer is basically correct. Just change this part:  `$('#MM label').each(...etc`  I would use `$(this).hide()` though instead of this.remove.